# How to use a .d.ts declaration file in a JS environment inside VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, .d.ts

I have been working on a JavaScript library, and want to document it using TypeScript declaration files. Now the problem is that I couldn't understand how to work with the file as I am developing the library in Visual Studio Code.

So I have set up this simple example.

Here's my directory structure:

```
learning
|-- index.js
|-- greeting.js
|-- greeting.d.ts
```

Suppose I have the following `greeting.d.ts` file that documents the class `Greeting`:

```
// greeting.d.ts
export class Greeting {
    constructor(msg: string)
    greet(): void
}
```

And here's the `greeting.js` file that defines the logic of the class `Greeting`:

```
// greeting.js
class Greeting {
    constructor(msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    greet() {
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
}

module.exports = Greeting;
```

This file is imported by `index.js` whereby I do a simple greeting:

```
// index.js
var Greeting = require('./greet.js');

var g = new Greeting('Hello World!');
g.greet();
```

As is clear, I am currently using the CommonJS-style modules.

Now, while I am working in my JS files (note that I am not working in a TypeScript environment — I want to use TypeScript *only for documentation purposes* for now), such as `index.js` and `greeting.js`, I want to be able to get intellisense based on the `greeting.d.ts` file.

I have tried many options, such as setting the `typeRoots` options in the `tsconfig.json` file placed inside the directory `learning`, or modifying the `include` property in the same `tsconfig.json` file, but none seems to be a solution.

How to use a .d.ts declaration file in a JS environment inside VSCode?

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?